# How to make a cookie available to all paths in a domain?

Tags: cookies, httpcookie

I created a cookie in a java filter and added back to the response

```
response.addCookie()
```

before returning to the client node.js application. This web application is accessed using a localhost URL in the browser. After reading about cookie domain issue while using 'localhost', i did not set any domain or path in the cookie, while creating it.

Now the Chrome or Firefox browsers don't show-up the cookie in the browser. All my URLs are http://localhost but, each page having different path.

Step 1: During a request to http://localhost/app/login cookie is created and set in the response  
Step 2: When the page loads after response, no cookies are shown in Chrome 
Step 3: During the next request http://localhost/app/customer the previously created cookie is not recieved when trying request.getCookies(). 
Step 4: Before returning back to client application, a cookie is created 
Step 5: Now the cookie created in Step 4 is shown in Chrome 
Step 6: The next request is also sent to http://localhost/app/customer , now the cookie created in step 4 is recieved in the server as well

***If cookie creation for localhost is an issue, how does it work for Steps 4-6 only ?***

> How can i make the created cookie available to all paths under the
>   localhost domain ? I tried using cookie.addPath("/") but, no change.

***Note***: Due to admin privilege issues in my development machine, i am not able to set-up a domain name to my localhost IP in etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 4):

In your Java server, you should call `cookie.setPath("/")` before adding it to response.

Such cookie will match all request URIs. It's a pity that it is not the default behavior.

I have a more detailed explanation of cookie path here - http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/http/Cookie.html#path

Comment: i tried calling .setPath("/") , after creating the cookie and before adding it to the response but, still it is this behavior.

Comment: what do you mean "cookie is not shown in firefox"? you check Options > Show Cookies, and it's not there? then we have a bigger problem.

Comment: i am using Chrome (due to some other problem with my Firefox). I am trying to see the cookie using the Chrome Menu Tools --> Developer Options --> Network --> Cookies

Comment: something wrong with `response.setCookie()` during `/app/login`; maybe post your code there?

Comment: @yathirigan another idea - try `cookie.setPath("/app")`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure path is the issue.  Path does not affect whether a cookie is created; it only determines whether it is presented.  If cookies aren't showing up in the browser's cookie jar they are being rejected for some reason other than path.

Chrome will not accept cookies for localhost because it does not accept cookies in the top level domain.  The domain in the URL has to have a dot in it somewhere.  So you could either add a hosts entry (recommended) or just trying using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Also, none of this will work if the cookie is marked as secure or is being set with a domain attribute.  If either of those is the case, you MUST use a hosts entry instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: i have added the exact steps to replicate my issue. If using localhost is an issue , why would it set the cookie correctly for Steps 4-6 (updated in the question) ?   som site was suggesting ".app.localhost" but, even that doesn't seems to work.

Comment: is having a host entry the only solution while using cookies in localhost ?

Comment: Are all the cookies the same with respect to the "secure" flag and the "domain" attribute?

Comment: i am not explicitly setting the Domain value and the secure flag.